# Empty connection managers when deploying SSIS packages unless converted to Package Connections

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssis-2016, ssis-2019

This is my first time starting from scratch with the "new" SSIS Integration Services Catalogs introduced in SQL 2012. I've developed packages with this new model for years but never set up my own environment.

I have packages that work in Visual Studio 2019 just fine and have project connection managers that will span across all of the packages in this project. When I deploy the packages the connection managers are empty in the package configuration.

Here's my project with the connections setup.

[image]

And here's what it looks like when I deploy the packages using the Project connections

[image]
[image]

If I change the connections to "Package Connections", the connections deploy as expected.

When I do this, the connection managers is populated
[image]
[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: You have the reputation, I'd propose putting some screenshots of what you're experiencing as I can't imagine how this looks. I'd suggest 1) what it looks like with project level connection manager 2) what it looks like with package connection managers 3) a reference pre-existing project level connection manager that shows what you're expecting

Comment: "When I deploy the packages the connection managers are empty in the package configuration." can you expand on this with screenshots? Do the packages run? If not, what's the error?

Comment: Sorry everyone. I've added pictures of what's happening

Answer (score 1):

Notice the Scope - GetWorkerData.dtsx  That's showing you what is configurable at the scope of the package. Since the connection managers at that point are Project level, you need to change the Scope to something different (I don't have a project level CM handy). Alternatively, right click on the project "Pull Data from ADP" and select configure from there. Then it will pop open that wizard with the correct scope selected.

Comment: TODO: edit answer with screenshots and TSQL of what Configuration does